# Question on kinematics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle is projected vertically upwards from point $A$ on the ground. It takes $T_1$ time to reach point $B$ but it still continues to move up. If it takes further $T_2$ time to reach ground from point $B$ then height of point $B$ would be?

Comment: My question was correct and the answer given was 1/2*g*t_1*t_2

Answer (score 2):

The particle continues moving until it reaches the maximum height. At maximum height its velocity vanishes. In return, it again takes $T1$ to travel from $B$ to the ground. So it takes $\tfrac{T2 -T1}{2}$ for it to travel from B to the maximum height. 
$V_0$ denotes for initial velocity of particle on the ground and $H(B)$ the height of B,
$$H(B)=-1/2*g(T1)^2 + V0(T1)$$
$$\text{at maximum height:}\;V = -g*(T1 + (T1 + T2)/2 ) + V0 = 0  $$
$$\text{so}\; V0 = g*(1.5*T1 + 0.5*T2)$$
substituting in first equation will get :
$$H (B) = 1/2 *g*T1* (2T1 + T2)$$